# rails how to render two format html/json in show action of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I would like to render json or html in show. For json format I would like to redner a json object, for html format I would like render  show.html.erb  view

here is my code

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format| 

      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

It returns an error of

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

when I test html format

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def show
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.xml  { render xml: @post}
       format.json { render json: @post}
 end
 end
```